# Google maps Api V3 multiple routes code don't work

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my code, I try to make that maps would show me multiple routes. I heard that I need multiple objects for that, but actually I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me?

```
<script>

    var mybr = document.createElement('br');

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat: -24.345, lng: 134.46}
        });

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          draggable: true,
          map: map,
        });

        var se = [ ["Telfer, WA", "Madura, WA"],
                   ["Newman, WA", "Zanthus, WA"],
                   ];

        for (i = 0; i < se.length; i++) {
        directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
          computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
        });

        displayRoute(se[i][0], se[i][1], directionsService,
            directionsDisplay);
        }

      }


      function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {

          var waypo = [];

          var wp = [ ["-26.170357", "126.535148"],
                     ["-23.715558", "133.889621"],
                     ["-20.719814", "139.486865"],
                     ["-30.877577", "143.568913"],                   
                   ];


        for (i = 0; i < wp.length; i++) { 
        waypo.push({
            location: new google.maps.LatLng(wp[i][0],wp[i][1] ),
            stopover: true
        });}


        service.route({
          origin: origin,
          destination: destination,
          waypoints: waypo,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING',
          avoidTolls: true
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            display.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: There is only one route in the posted code.  How are you trying to add multiple routes?  Are you looking for route alternatives? Those don't work with waypoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show multiple routes, you will need to set provideRouteAlternatives to true in the request object. You can then use the directionsRenderer object to display the routes. Here is some sample code of this:

```
directionsService.route({
origin: "Houston, TX",
destination: "Austin, TX",
travelMode: 'DRIVING',
provideRouteAlternatives: true
}, function(response, status) {
if (status === 'OK') {
  for (var i = 0; i < response.routes.length; i++){
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    if(i <= 0)
      directionsDisplay.setOptions({
          polylineOptions: {
                          strokeColor: 'blue'
                           }
       });
     else
        directionsDisplay.setOptions({
          polylineOptions: {
                          strokeColor: 'red'
                           }
       });
     directionsDisplay.setRouteIndex(i);
     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }
} else {
  window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
}
});
```

I have this demonstrated on a JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Ly3xqqo4/1/

Please be advised that you will need to insert your own API key to use the fiddle.

I hope this helps!